# How to redirect to homepage from any path in github pages?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, github, github-pages

I tried to redirect to homepage by adding this meta tag inside 404.html file :

```
 <meta
      http-equiv="refresh"
      content="0; URL='https://gittestfor.github.io'"
    />
```

And it works fine the first time but the second the page gets cached it doesn't work .

When I clear site data in the application tab in developer console , it works .

[image]

How can I disable this behaviour or redirect from any path to homepage "/" with github pages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding a 404.html file to the root of the project in github pages repo and added this code to that file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      http-equiv="refresh"
      content="0; URL='https://username.github.io'"
    />
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Now every request other than `https://username.github.io/` like `.../name` will be redirected to the homepage which is `/` .

Note : This behaviour works only when the page is not cached in the browser and there is no service worker to cache the website .